# Check if a selection exists in vimscript

Tags: vim

I want to write a function in [vimscript](/questions/tagged/vimscript) that echoes the selected text or, if no text is selected, the entire buffer.

How can I distinguish between these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a function to get `visually selected text`.
I hope it can help you.

```
function! GetSelected()

    " save reg
    let reg = '"'
    let reg_save = getreg(reg)
    let reg_type = getregtype(reg)

    " yank visually selected text
    silent exe 'norm! gv"'.reg.'y'
    let value = getreg(reg)

    " restore reg
    call setreg(reg,reg_save,reg_type)

    return value

endfun

" viusal map
vnoremap gs :<C-U>echo GetSelected()<CR>

" normal map
nnoremap gs :<C-U>echo join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")<CR>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly? Your answer probably helps the ensamgud, but future reader might want to read a bit more info here.

Answer (score 4):

Define two mappings, an `:nmap` using the entire buffer, and a `:vmap` for the selected text. Both can invoke the same function, passing an `isVisual` boolean flag or a `mode` argument.

Anything else (custom commands, direct function `:call`) would require an explicit hint, because in order to invoke them, visual mode as already been left (for command-line mode). You also cannot use the `'<,'>` marks for the detection, because they will keep the *last* selection even after it has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `line("'<") > 0` to check whether the selection mark exists.